# CHAR and VARCHAR lengths for multibyte characters

Tags: mysql, varchar, utf-8

I have a table with ~100mln rows. One of the columns is a `VARCHAR(64)` with `utf8mb4` encoding for storing user nicknames (others are few integers).

The data in that column has `MAX(LENGTH()) == 42` and `MAX(CHAR_LENGTH()) == 24` (I can attach an image of distribution of lengths if needed). ~90% of rows only use ASCII characters.

From the MySQL docs,

> CHAR(30) can hold up to 30 characters. [...]
> a CHAR(255) column can exceed 768 bytes

So does it mean it can store N characters, even multibyte? How about a varchar, does the specified size mean bytes or characters?

My table is mostly write-intensive (`INSERT O.D.K. UPDATE`). Is it a good idea to switch to constant-length field (especially with such not-very-long strings) versus having them as a varying-length field, probably stored somewhere else on the disk?

Byte length distribution:

[image: Byte length distribution]

Char_length distribution:

[image: Char_length distribution]

Comment: What version of MySQL are you running?  (I need this before jumping on max lengths.)

Comment: A utf8mb4 _character_ takes between 1 and 4 _bytes_.  The 768 must be referring to utf8, not utf8mb4.  `CHAR` and `VARCHAR` refer to _characters_.

Comment: "switch to constant-length field" -- NO.  (Except if they are truly fixed length, such as country_code, zipcode, etc.)

Comment: @RickJames Ver 8.0.34
Yes, it was written that for an encoding that uses more than 3 bytes per character (like `mb4`) the `CHAR(255)` can exceed `3*256` bytes. Obviously.
So now the only question is whether it is worth to reduce the length of my `varchar` column (or maybe switch to `varbinary`?). I've added the distribution plots to the post.

Comment: Looks like the average byte (or character) length of your strings is around 13.  So, a `VARCHAR(..)` would consume, on average, 2+13 bytes.  While `CHAR(20) would always take 20 bytes.  Less space is better.

Comment: @RickJames Btw, does `char` reserve the specified character count times max bytes per char? I have trouble wrapping my head around such concept of storing N varying size characters in a constant length field. LoL.
Also, does it matter for writing speed, that the strings have to be stored somewhere outside the row? Is it better for reading speed, when that column is not needed?
Also x2, so is there any difference if I switched from current `varchar(64)` to f.e. `varchar(25)` which should still fit all strings? Or maybe `varbinary(45)`?

Comment: _With InnoDB_, I _think_ the storage is the same for `CHAR` as `VARCHAR`.  `CHAR` has the semantics of requiring space-padding.  When building a temp table, `CHAR` was stretched to a max length * bytes-per-char.  But I think that has even been eliminated.  (Perhaps the padding is kept, but only 1 byte per space for utf8.)  Bottom line: `CHAR`.is virtually useless, especially for performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So does it mean it can store N characters, even multibyte? How about a
> varchar, does the specified size mean bytes or characters?

Yes, the length is measured in characters, not bytes.
See also the docs for [BINARY/VARBINARY data types](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/binary-varbinary.html)

> Is it a good idea to switch to constant-length field (especially with
> such not-very-long strings) versus having them as a varying-length
> field, probably stored somewhere else on the disk?

No. Constant length fields will always occupy the maximum possible space, while varchars will usually occupy much less space.
Less space means more rows per disk page, thus less page reads/writes and less memory needed.

Also see [this question for CHAR/VARCHAR comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7601424/any-benefit-of-uses-char-over-varchar)

Comment: `CHAR is also better than VARCHAR for data that’s changed frequently, because a fixed-length row is not prone to fragmentation.`
That was one of the reasons I asked about moving to constant-length - almost all rows are updated at least daily (though I know that it may not be much compared to abilities of DBMS)

Comment: @herhor67 it would matter if that field (the nickname) changed frequently, but I suppose that is not the column which is updated more.

Comment: All fields are updated from the external API. Yes, they usually don't "change", but they are still in the insert query.

Comment: @herhor67 if the new value has the same length of the old value,  the row has the same length and there is no fragmentation

Comment: @herhor67 - That old wives' tale about `CHAR` applied to `ENGINE=MyISAM`, not `InnoDB`.

Comment: @AndreaB. - InnoDB will temporarily hold the old and new copy of the row during `UPDATE`' this threatens fragmentation more than fixed/dynamic length.

Comment: Your first link refers to `BINARY`, not `CHAR`.  Your other link is to a 12-year-old Question -- it is out of date.  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/char.html should be definitive, but iI believe it, too, is out of date.

Comment: @herhor67 you could also consider using a separate table for the `CHAR`/`VARCHAR` values with integer primary key and just having an integer foreign key in your current table, if the set of values is rarely changed and most of the changes are between existing values.